# Force Big figure of 4x8 subfigures appear in one page

Tags: positioning, subfloats

I have a big figure of 4x8 subfigures and i want to force it in one page as now it displays around 20 subfigures and the rest don't appear.

Update:

I have tried writing this in the line:

```
\includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight]
```

but its giving an error

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight]
\centering
```

Comment: If it doesn't fit then you need to shrink the images to make them fit onto one page?  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  You can use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` so that the actual images do not need to provided.

Comment: I've tried to put this \includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight] after the \begin{figure*}[t!] to be \begin{figure*}[t!]
\includegraphics[height=0.8\textheight]
\centering but its saying there is an error

Comment: Are the individual pictures named systematically, like `figure1.png`, `figure2.png`, ... , `figure32.png`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % calculate textwidth and textheight in cm; usually one would divide by 28.453, the 29 was chosen to avoid overfull boxes
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytextwidth}{\textwidth/29}\mytextwidth
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytextheight}{\textheight/29}\mytextheight

        % cycle through 32 numbers; you'll need to set the scaling only once; the "draw" in the node options is to show the boundaries of each picture, simply remove it once you found the right scaling factor
        % I didn't have 32 pictures ready, but if they're named systematically, you can use e.g.
        %       \includegraphics[scale=1.1]{figure\x.png}
        % which will produce "figure0.png" to "figure31.png".
        % If the numbers start at a different index, you can use
        %       \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using \x+5] in {0,...,31}
        % and then
        %       \includegraphics[scale=1.1]{figure\y.png} 
        % to produce "figure5.png" to "figure36.png"
        \foreach \x in {0,...,31}
        {   \node[below right,draw] at ({\mytextwidth/4*mod(\x,4)},{\mytextheight/8*div(\x,4)}) {\includegraphics[scale=1.04]{book.png}};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{The same book over and over.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have package like graphicx loaded. Then write
`\scalebox{0.75}{Your matrix of figures}`. Certainly, 0.75 is only an approximation of the correct value.

Comment: Where to write this? I've updated the question

Comment: it would be `\scalebox{factor}{\includegraphics...}`

Comment: @user1460166: May you try if the following example works? `\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t!]
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{golfer}\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{golfer}

\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{golfer}\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{golfer}
\end{figure}

\end{document}`
I am afraid that you may use commands from graphicX with graphicS (the difference) capitalized. Might you give the whole file in your quastion?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke this will work but the problem with me that I don't want to rescale the subfigures. I mean is there a way or parameter to give it to the big figure instead of scaling every subfigure? as I have 32 subfigs

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Przemyslaw's answer, you can use the `scale` key to `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics[scale=.75]{path/to/image}
```